# How to bind to unknown property name at development time

Tags: vue.js, dynamic, data-binding, binding, v-model

The following correctly binds to a property on my model

```
      <v-checkbox
        v-if="header.dataType === 'Toggle'"
        v-model="myprops.item.superColumn"
        @change="onChanged(myprops.item)"
      ></v-checkbox>
```

as does this

```
      <v-checkbox
        v-if="header.dataType === 'Toggle'"
        v-model="myprops.item['superColumn']"
        @change="onChanged(myprops.item)"
      ></v-checkbox>
```

but both of these require that I know the name of the property at development time, which I do not.

The following does not work

```
      <v-checkbox
        v-if="header.dataType === 'Toggle'"
        v-model="myprops.item[header.columnName]"
        @change="onChanged(myprops.item)"
      ></v-checkbox>
```

header.columnName is a string and exists as I can use it for other properties on the checkbox such as a hint or an id.

any thoughts?  I'm new to vue.js, javascript, the web.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with what you are doing. Even the third syntax should work. See the Codepen for more details: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zeEmLa?editors=1010#anon-login Ensure that you have properly set `columnName`.

Comment: These are all valid JS syntaxes. If one syntax works, so should others.

Comment: The third example definitely does not work for me;  I created a function to see what's happening and the result of myprops.item[header.columnName] is the boolean value that the myprops.item's property is holding;  not the property name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as below

```
<v-checkbox
        v-if="header.dataType === 'Toggle'"
        v-model="myprops.item[''+header['columnName']]"
        @change="onChanged(myprops.item)"
      ></v-checkbox>
```

Comment: This works, Thank you.  Could you provide me a link or a term to google for this type of access?

Comment: Well that's a javascript concept i just converted the value to the string by appending it to empty quotes so your value can be accessed.

Comment: You can edit your question title with some tags like dynamic bindings to v-model and kindly accept the answer so the question is closed and it may be helpful to others too.